# Looping program based on user input

Tags: python, if-statement

I am making a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors where after the game has ended it displays to the screen 'Would you like to play again?". I am struggling to get the game to run again when the user selects yes. I am able to have the program say goodbye and quite when the user selects no.

I could copy and paste the code inside the If statement if the user selects yes a bunch of times but this is very inefficient and I feel there must be an easier way.

```
import random
selection = ("Rock", "Paper", "Scissors")
user1 = input("Pick Rock, Paper, or Scissors: ").upper()
computer = random.choice(selection)
if (user1 == "ROCK"):
        if (computer == "Paper"):
            print ("The computer selected: " + (computer))
            print ("You lost")
        elif (computer == "Scissors"):
            print ("The computer selected: " + (computer))
            print ("You win")
        elif (computer == "Rock"):
            print ("The computer selected: " + (computer))
            print ("Tie")
        else:
            print ("Uh oh something went wrong. Please try again")
elif (user1 == "PAPER"):
            if (computer == "Scissors"):
                print ("The computer selected: " + (computer))
                print ("You lost")
            elif (computer == "Rock"):
                print ("The computer selected: " + (computer))
                print ("You win")
            elif (computer == "Paper"):
                print ("The computer selected: " + (computer))
                print ("Tie")
            else:
                print ("Uh oh something went wrong. Please try again")
elif (user1 == "SCISSORS"):
        if (computer == "Rock"):
            print ("The computer selected: " + (computer))
            print ("You lost")
        elif (computer == "Paper"):
            print ("The computer selected: " + (computer))
            print ("You win")
        elif (computer == "Scissors"):
            print ("The computer selected: " + (computer))
            print ("Tie")
        else:
                print ("Uh oh something went wrong. Please try again")
else:
            print ("Invalid Selection")
while True:
    # main program
    while True:
        answer = input('Run again? (y/n): ')
        if answer in ('y', 'n'):
            break
        print ('Invalid input.')
    if answer == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        print ('Goodbye')
        break
```

My expected result is when the user types "y" and hits enter the game will start again but as of now when the user types "y" it just repeats the same "Would you like to play again. I understand it does that because I don't have any actual code inside the If statement but I don't know what I need to add to it to get the desired result.

Comment: You need to put the while loop over the big block of if statements

Comment: In these cases I prefer to create a class with functions, from there I run the game in while loop.

Answer (score 0):

When you type Continue it will keep repeating the statement over and over

here is the solve for your code

```
import random


while Continue:
    selection = ("Rock", "Paper", "Scissors")
    user1 = input("Pick Rock, Paper, or Scissors: ").upper()
    computer = random.choice(selection)
    if (user1 == "ROCK"):
            if (computer == "Paper"):
                print ("The computer selected: " + (computer))
                print ("You lost")
            elif (computer == "Scissors"):
                print ("The computer selected: " + (computer))
                print ("You win")
            elif (computer == "Rock"):
                print ("The computer selected: " + (computer))
                print ("Tie")
            else:
                print ("Uh oh something went wrong. Please try again")
    elif (user1 == "PAPER"):
                if (computer == "Scissors"):
                    print ("The computer selected: " + (computer))
                    print ("You lost")
                elif (computer == "Rock"):
                    print ("The computer selected: " + (computer))
                    print ("You win")
                elif (computer == "Paper"):
                    print ("The computer selected: " + (computer))
                    print ("Tie")
                else:
                    print ("Uh oh something went wrong. Please try again")
    elif (user1 == "SCISSORS"):
            if (computer == "Rock"):
                print ("The computer selected: " + (computer))
                print ("You lost")
            elif (computer == "Paper"):
                print ("The computer selected: " + (computer))
                print ("You win")
            elif (computer == "Scissors"):
                print ("The computer selected: " + (computer))
                print ("Tie")
            else:
                print ("Uh oh something went wrong. Please try again")
    else:
        print ("Invalid Selection")

    answer = input('Run again? (y/n): ')
    while True:
        if answer in ('y', 'n'):
            print ('Invalid input.')
        if answer == 'y':
            Continue = True
        else:
            print ('Goodbye')
            Continue = False
            break
```

Comment: ok so do I have to define Continue as true? And how would I go about getting the game to start over?

Comment: @BrianMuhic it's a boolean variable you can name whatever you want

Comment: you can also do `while answer is "y":` in the top loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function:

```
def play_game():
    selection = ("Rock", "Paper", "Scissors")
    user1 = input("Pick Rock, Paper, or Scissors: ").upper()
    computer = random.choice(selection)
    # ...
    # ...
    # ...
    else:
        print ("Invalid Selection")
```

And call it depending on user input in a loop like:

```
play_game()    
while True:
    answer = input('Run again? (y/n): ')
    if answer.lower() == 'y':
        play_game()
    elif answer.lower() == 'n':
        break
    else:
        print ('Invalid input.')
```

Comment: ok this worked really well thank you . I removed the print invalid input under the break because it would print that after every selection made.

Comment: @BrianMuhic, oops. Missed an `else` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could also include the while loop in the game function if you wanted

```
import random
import time

class RockPaperScissors:

    def __init__(self):
        self.elements = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
        self.valid_inputs = ['1','2','3']

    def win_checker(self, cpu_choice, user_choice):
        if ((user_choice == '2' and cpu_choice == 'rock')
        or (user_choice == '1' and cpu_choice == 'scissors')
        or(user_choice == '3' and cpu_choice == 'paper')):
            print('YOU WON')
        else:
            print('You Lost. Computer chose, ', cpu_choice.upper())

    def input_validator(self, user_input):
        if user_input in self.valid_inputs:
            return True

    def play_again(self):
       if input("Do You Want To Play Again? Y/N?").lower() == 'y':
           return True
       else: return False

    def game(self):
        for option in self.elements:
            print(option)
            time.sleep(1)
        user_guess = input('1: Rock, 2:Paper, 3:Scissors: ')
        if self.input_validator == True:
            cpu_choice = random.choice(self.elements)
            self.win_checker(cpu_choice,user_guess)
        else: print('Invalid Input')

play_again = True
while play_again == True:      
    RockPaperScissors().game()
    play_again = RockPaperScissors().play_again()
```